# Empty a table that was filled via RactJS / Axios(this.props)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I fetch the data via Axios->Reducer then wrap it with React-Redux(@connect) and dispatch it into props:

```
this.props.dispatch(fetchContacts(this.state.searchParam));
```

And then let ReactJS render the table.

I want to reset all filter and empty a table if the user press ESC.
I'm new to ReactJS so i don't know all the rules yet, but it seems like you shouldn't touch the DOM by yourself to avoid issues.

My try looks like:

```
let tbody = document.getElementById('contactList').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
//Empty table
while (tbody.firstChild) {
  tbody.removeChild(tbody.firstChild);
}
```

But if i do it like that i will get the following error when i try to load a new dataset:

> test.js:6210 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute
>   'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
>       at removeChild

How can I tell reactJS to empty the table or at least tell it that it is already empty?

Or what I think I have to do, reset the props?
It seems not so straight forward to change the props in react.

Comment: Call another method removeContacts from actions when user presses esc key. Return some action type 'REMOVE_CONTACTS' to the reducer and in the reducer just empty the state property. This will return empty object to the container where you are calling mapStateToProps. This will rerender the table with no data.

Comment: Yeah that worked, could have thought about that... thanks

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: @Trinu Would be good if you can post that as answer so this can be "closed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all another method removeContacts from actions when user presses esc key. Return some action type 'REMOVE_CONTACTS' to the reducer and in the reducer just empty the state property. This will return empty object to the container where you are calling mapStateToProps. This will rerender the table with no data.